# Describing a string matrix in a wsdl file

Tags: java, wsdl

How can I describe in the wsdl file the type "matrix of string"?

for the array :

```
class A {
String [] d;
}
```

in wsdl is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="A">
    <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name ="d" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and for matrix?

```
class A {
    String [][] d;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "matrix"? A two-dimensional array of strings?

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of what that would look like?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. You could have a `sequence` of `complexType` that exists of `sequence` - but that would give you Java code like

```
@XmlElement(name = "d")
protected List<A.D> ds;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "ds"
})
public static class D {
    @XmlElement(name = "d")
    protected List<String> ds;

    public List<String> getDS() {
        if (ds == null) {
            ds = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.ds;
    }
}
```

If you must have a two-dimensional `String[][]`, you will have to transform the `List<A.D>` into `String[][]` yourself.